# Remove BS4 jQuery document.focus event programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, focus, event-listener

I have a `Bootstrap 4` text field that I cannot give focus to. I have tried:

- Clicking in the field
- Using jQuery focus in console
- Tabbing to it
- Assigning `autofocus` attribute

When I look in chrome devtools `Elements > EventListeners` tab, go down to focus and remove the `focus` `EventListeners`, the field can get focus again. Also if I remove `focusin` listener it works.

I have tried in the console:

- jQuery `.off` on the document object
  `$(document).off( "focusin");`
- jQuery `.off` on the window object

and

```
var customFunction = function (event) {

    document.removeEventListener('focus',customFunction, false );

};
document.addEventListener("focus", customFunction, false);
```

[Live Page](https://codethaglobe.github.io/fundo-sigUI-v1/app/#)

Here is what I mean about the devtools event listener screen

[DevTools Screenshot with Annotation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfEEv.png)

Not really sure what to do next. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I now think this has to do with the auto-show of the modal I am using for dev. This way I don't have to manually open the modal every time I refresh. I removed it and the field would take ficus, but the modal wouldn't open.

Comment: This resolved the issue on the click event that shows my custom overlay on top of a bootstrap modal:

     $(document).off("focusin");
     $(document).off("focus");

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue by removing jQuery's document.focus() EventListener which was blocking the input for some reason.

```
$btnSignContracts.on('click', function(e) {
    $(document).off("focusin");
    $(document).off("focus");
});
```

The field is working properly now.